# Impossible to access another port with curl and php

Tags: php, curl, xampp, pentaho

I'm trying to use basic authentication with curl and php to access Pentaho server. I'm using XAMPP on port 81 and Pentaho on port 8080.

The problem is that it searches Pentaho on port 81. I have tried both adding the port after the host (`localhost:8080`) and using the curl option (`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);`).

If I access any other URL, it works.

I think it only works with the default port 80 and the current port (in this case 81), but not with the rest. How can I change the configuration to work with a port other than the default?

*Edit: I don't want to change the Pentaho's port. What I want is to make CURL works with the specified port.*

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pentaho bi server with the bundled tomcat, you can change the port pentaho is running on in `biserver-ee/tomcat/conf/server.xml`. the port number next to `protocol="HTTP/1.1"`

if that's not what you are trying to do, please can you be more specific in the question?